# Delete a file object after use in python

Tags: python, file, flask

Let's say that I read a file(CSV) which is uploaded from input form, and then I process it :

```
file = request.files['file']
filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

#using the file object to predict result
df=pd.read_csv(file)
results = model.predict(df.v2)

#saving the file requested from the form to a dir
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
return results
```

Once this is executed the file 'test.csv' is uploaded in a dir as of now. What is the cleanest way to remove (delete) the `file` object?

Comment: `os.remove()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove

Comment: Well, I believe that you save this file to disk first? If so, you may consider saving it to temporary directory: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#module-tempfile

Comment: I assume you have a `with open(filename, "r") as fp:` contained in the `...`. That context management syntax in python automatically closes the file handler that the `with open...` stuff opens when you come out of that code block. Unless by "delete the file object" you mean "delete the file" in which case `os.remove` as per ltd's comment.

Comment: Thank you for the informations :)

Comment: This is resolved os.remove() worked